# Appending array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a problem with appending array like this:

```
var medicine = [(String, String?)]()
```

From Parse SDK i get two arrays:

`medicinesNames = ["Zyrtec", "medicine1", "medicine2"]` and
`let amountName = ["2 times a day" , "in the morning", "after lunch"]`

**The question is how to append my property array with strings in those arrays  ?**
I want to append it in separate functions. Output of 1st fun:
`[("Zyrtec", nil), ("medicine1", nil)... ]`
And after the second fun i want to get the property something like this:
`[("Zyrtec", "2 times a day"), ("Medicine1", "in the morning"),...]`

Comment: please show the desired outcome, you have two string arrays and one optional array of tuples - generally if you want to be able to append something to arrays or dictionaries defines them using `var` rather than `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something more concise that doing this via two functions:

```
let medicinesNames = ["Zyrtec", "medicine1", "medicine2"]
let amountName = ["2 times a day" , "in the morning", "after lunch"]

let medicine = Array(zip(medicinesNames, amountName))
```

The type of `medicine` will be `[(String, String)]`, and the value will be:

```
[("Zyrtec", "2 times a day"), ("medicine1", "in the morning"), ("medicine2", "after lunch")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of tuples from two separate arrays can be achieved with a repeat loop

```
var medicine = [(String, String?)]()

let medicinesNames = ["Zyrtec", "medicine1", "medicine2"]
let amountName = ["2 times a day" , "in the morning", "after lunch"]
assert(medicinesNames.count == amountName.count, "both arrays must contain the same number of items")
for i in 0..<medicinesNames.count {
  medicine.append((medicinesNames[i], amountName[i]))
}
```

Actually a medication without a time is unlikely, I'd recommend to declare the array non-optional `[(String, String)]`